# How to pass Material-UI FlatButton CSS into other Button component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using a loading button object in my website (https://github.com/mathieudutour/react-progress-button), and I'm trying to pass the Material-UI FlatButton CSS into it so that it looks the same as the FlatButton. However, I'm not sure how to do this.

```
import ProgressButton from 'react-progress-button'

const App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState () {
    return {
      buttonState: ''
    }
  },

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <ProgressButton onClick={this.handleClick} state={this.state.buttonState}
style={//flat button CSS goes here.....}>
          Go!
        </ProgressButton>
      </div>
    )
  },

  handleClick () {
    this.setState({buttonState: 'loading'})
    // make asynchronous call
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({buttonState: 'success'})
    }, 3000)
  }
})
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an invisible flat button and get the style by using something like:

```
<FlatButton id="mock1"/> 
let flatButtonStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('mock1'));
```

Then assign it to `<ProgressButton>`. You might have to modify the CSS style object a bit since it is returning you all the computed styles.

```
<ProgressButton onClick={this.handleClick} state={this.state.buttonState} style={this.flatButtonStyle}>
```

For example in your code
    import ProgressButton from 'react-progress-button'

```
const App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState () {
    return {
      buttonState: ''
    }
  },

  render () {
    let flatButtonStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('mock1'));
    return (
      <div>
        <FlatButton id="mock1"/>
        <ProgressButton onClick={this.handleClick} state={this.state.buttonState}
style={this.flatButtonStyle}>
          Go!
        </ProgressButton>
      </div>
    )
  },

  handleClick () {
    this.setState({buttonState: 'loading'})
    // make asynchronous call
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({buttonState: 'success'})
    }, 3000)
  }
})
```

This should give you a roughly idea. You have to modify the code a little bit to make it work.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think you could place your code into the code I wrote in the OP? I'm unsure where to place it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting an error message "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'

Comment: If you are curious about performance then Avoid using `getComputedStyle`